# SUM/COUNT of CASE within CASE in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, count, sum, case

Have below Column in table product :

```
a  |  b  | cat
--------------
2  |  4  |  1
3  |  1  |  1
4  |  4  |  1
2  |  1  |  1
3  |  2  |  1
5  |  3  |  1
8  |  7  |  2
5  |  3  |  2


$sql = "SELECT 
        SUM(CASE 
            WHEN
            cat = 1
            AND
            a > b  
            THEN 1 else 0 end) as prdplus
        FROM product
       ";
```

> in above query i am getting value for *sum or count*  of **a** greater
>   then **b**

which is  3>1 , 2>1 , 3>2 , 5>3

hence output of above query will be : ***4***

```
prdplus
-------
4
```

> ***what i need*** is **count value have only +1** *in above count* of **4**

thats with above query now i need +1 value count

```
3-1 = 2
2-1 = 1  // just explanation purpose , output i need in -> plus1 
3-2 = 1  // just explanation purpose , output i need in  -> plus1
5-3 = 2
```

hence with above query  i need only +1 count which is **2**

i am not getting how to write case within case including above query as i need both count to show in my table as below

***Output Final :***

```
 prdplus | plus1 
----------------
  4      |  2
```

Comment: Please explain the `plus1` in your final output.

Comment: plus1 is count of +1 from output prdplus , pls see // just explanation purpose , output i need is below

Comment: Could you explain what exactly you're doing and what you want to achieve.

Comment: prdplus = 4 which from query where a>b , 
so now i need to find how much +1 ,+2 ,+3 count are there in  prdplus = 4 , but for currently i need only +1 count from prdplus = 4

Comment: So, where a=b+1 :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN a > b  
                THEN 1 
                else 0 
           end) as prdplus,
       SUM(CASE WHEN a - b = 1  
                THEN 1 
                else 0 
           end) as prdplus1
FROM product
```

Comment: thanks i think its working .... but as i have more join with my query will check properly afterwards

Comment: one question what if i need -1 count , (CASE WHEN a - b = '-1' THEN 1 
else 0  end)   or  (CASE WHEN a - b = -1 THEN 1 
else 0  end)

Comment: bro what if i need to count = value , thats : CASE WHEN a = b = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0

Comment: hey can you pls help @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41826230/sum-case-union-groupby-php-mysql

Answer (score 1):

Check This.

```
        SELECT 
                SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN
                    a > b  
                    THEN 1 else 0 end) as prdplus  
                   , 
                      SUM(CASE WHEN a - b = 1  
                        THEN 1 
                        else 0 
                   end) as plus1 

                FROM 
                (


        select 2 as a  , 4 as b union
        select 3   , 1 union
        select 4   ,  4 union
        select 2   , 1 union
        select 3   , 2 union
        select 5   , 3
                )
         a
```

Comment: instead of its you can use your table name ..its simple

Comment: actually is same as juergen d

Comment: its seem to be ... but i am checking as my records are more ... above question have dummy value ....

Comment: thanks i think its working .... but as i have more join with my query will check properly afterwards

Comment: one question what if i need -1 count , (CASE WHEN a - b = '-1' THEN 1 
else 0  end)   or  (CASE WHEN a - b = -1 THEN 1 
else 0  end)

Comment: you can write as it is. explain in details if u gettign error or wrong result

Comment: its working , a - b = '-1'  , but i am not getting the result is proper or not has there is too much combination

Comment: add sample data with desried output

Comment: bro what if i need to count = value , thats : CASE WHEN a = b = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0

Comment: Add Line " SUM(CASE WHEN a = 0 and b=0 THEN 1  else 0 end) as plus1 "

Comment: hey can you pls help me @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41826230/sum-case-union-groupby-php-mysql