# Sum,Case,Union,Group by : Php Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, sum, union

SUM CASE not showing proper details

**Sample date :**

> **below is data with group by prdid**

```
wghvalue    prdid  addby  cutequl
0.4         57546    me     1
0.6         71256    me     1
0.2         68754    me     1
```

> **below is data when i remove group by prdid**

```
wghvalue    prdid  addby  cutequl
0.1         57546    me     1
0.1         57546    me     1
0.2         57546    me     1
0.1         71256    me     1
0.5         71256    me     1
0.2         68754    me     1
```

one strange thing :

in above sample data

```
prdb.order  cutid.order
    2           2
    3           2
    4           4
```

so if i am writing query

> prdb.order - cutid.order as newval

i am getting value like ... 2-2 = 0 , 3-2 = 1 , 4-4 =0

but same for

> sum(case when prdb.order - cutid.order = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as newval

getting value like ... 3 , 2 , 1

i think bove value 3,2,1 not getting group by prdid

below is query

```
SELECT 
    sum(t1.count) as count,
    sum(t1.wghvalue) as wghvalue,
    t1.addby,
    SUM(t1.cutequl) as cutequl
FROM 
    (SELECT  
        COUNT(pl.id) as count,
        SUM(pl.wghvalue) as wghvalue
        addby,
        SUM(CASE 
            WHEN prdb.cutaname = cutid.cutname
                 AND prdb.order = cutid.order
                 AND prdb.order - cutid.order = 0  
            THEN 1 
            else 0 
        end) as cutequl
    FROM 
        product AS prod
        LEFT JOIN producta AS prda ON prod.id = prda.id
        LEFT JOIN prdoctb AS prdb ON prod.pid = prda.pid 
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT id, wghvalue, addby, prdid
                    FROM prdentrya
                    WHERE 1=1 
                    GROUP BY prdid
                    UNION
                    SELECT id, wghvalue, addby, prdid
                    FROM prdentryb
                    WHERE 1=1
                    GROUP BY prdid
                   ) AS pl ON( pl.prdid = prda.prdid  )
        LEFT JOIN cut AS cutid ON prdb.cutaname = cutid.cutname  
    WHERE 
        pl.aadby = 103 
    GROUP BY 
        pl.prdid
    ORDER BY
        pl.prdid ASC,
        pl.aadby ASC 
    ) t1
group by t1.addby
```

**Output coming from above query is :**

```
count | wghvalue | addby | cutequl 
3     |  1.2     |  me   |   6
```

**What i should get as below**

```
count | wghvalue | addby | cutequl 
3     |  1.2     |  me   |   3
```

i think **GROUP BY prdid** is not working in sum case , 
how i can include that in sum case.

thanks

Comment: SUM(CASE is well formed.

Comment: yes... but value coming in that is not proper .....GROUP BY prdid is not working in that ... as if i remove GROUP BY prdid from whole query what result i see for count is 22 .... hence after applying GROUP BY prdid its showing proper count ...but on sum case thats cutequl ...i am not getting proper value

Comment: hey you der ?....

Comment: yes, I'm trying to decipher, it's a long query and quite difficult to evaluate without any data.

Comment: please see edit question, i have tried to put some sample data

Comment: u still there??...

Comment: cutequl = 3 ? how .? can you explain logic ?

Comment: thats i dont know ... i think its not taking GROUP BY prdid  , hence if u see sample its shows 3 repeated for  prdid =57546  , so might be that count = 3

Comment: bro still waiting for You :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Try To store result into temp Table.
Then use SUM operation on It.

```
                CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TempTemp AS
                (
                    SELECT  
                        COUNT(pl.id) as count,
                        SUM(pl.wghvalue) as wghvalue
                        addby,
                        SUM(CASE 
                            WHEN prdb.cutaname = cutid.cutname
                                 AND prdb.order = cutid.order
                                 AND prdb.order - cutid.order = 0  
                            THEN 1 
                            WHEN prdb.order is null or prdb.cutaname  is null THEN 1
                            else 0 
                        end) as cutequl
                    FROM 
                        product AS prod
                        LEFT JOIN producta AS prda ON prod.id = prda.id
                        LEFT JOIN prdoctb AS prdb ON prod.pid = prda.pid 
                        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT id, wghvalue, addby, prdid
                                    FROM prdentrya
                                    WHERE 1=1 
                                    GROUP BY prdid
                                    UNION
                                    SELECT id, wghvalue, addby, prdid
                                    FROM prdentryb
                                    WHERE 1=1
                                    GROUP BY prdid
                                   ) AS pl ON( pl.prdid = prda.prdid  )
                        LEFT JOIN cut AS cutid ON prdb.cutaname = cutid.cutname  
                    WHERE 
                        pl.aadby = 103 
                    GROUP BY 
                        pl.prdid
                    ORDER BY
                        pl.prdid ASC,
                        pl.aadby ASC 
                )


                SELECT 
                    sum(t1.count)  , sum(t1.wghvalue) ,t1.addby,SUM(t1.cutequl) , From 
                    TempTemp t1 
                    group by addby
```